# kubernetes cron runs when node pools are scaled

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have created kubernetes cron job to perform a scheduled task and it runs periodically at the scheduled time. But it also runs when the node pools are scaled up.

Node pools are scaled down one by one everyday night and scaled up in the morning. Auto scaling is disabled when scaling down and enabled when scaling up.  When scaling up, cron job runs and executes the scheduled task which is not scheduled at that time.

cron yaml -

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: app-cron
  labels:
    run: app-cron
spec:
  schedule: "1 0 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 3
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: app-cron
              image: curlimages/curl
              command: [ "curl", "$(SERVICE_HOST_KEY)" ]
              env:
                - name: SERVICE_HOST_KEY
                  valueFrom:
                    configMapKeyRef:
                      name: cron-config
                      key: SERVICE_HOST
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

How can I stop running cron at the node pool scaling up time ?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  I'd be surprised if a Kubernetes CronJob decided to run whenever new nodes are added (if your environment uses the cluster autoscaler this could happen pretty routinely).

Comment: Please, add your Kubernetes configuration files.

Comment: @Alez updated with cron yaml

Comment: @DavidMaze Auto-scaling is enabled when scaling up the node-pools. Can we fix it by adding any configuration to cron config.

Comment: We also need the autoscaler configuration